# Extend angular filter for number in array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-filters

I have elements of the form:

```
{ number: 1, name: 'name1', selected:[100,400,210,103,102], ... },
{ number: 2, name: 'name2', selected:[100,400,210,104,102], ... },
{ number: 3, name: 'name3', selected:[100,103], ... }
```

(... are other string attributes)

My goal is to write an efficient angular filter to make filtering via the `$` property possible while other I can also filter the `selected` array with the function of a contains filter.

> Note that a named property will match properties on the same level
>   only, while the special $ property will match properties on the same
>   level or deeper. E.g. an array item like
>   `{name: {first: 'John', last: 'Doe'}}`
>   will not be matched by `{name: 'John'}`, but will be matched by
>   `{$: 'John'}`.

Filtering with the filter `{$: 'name', selected[100,103]}` should e.g. return the first and the third element above. Is it possible with simply writing a filter that will filter the selected (which I did) and chaining it with another filter? Or is it even possible without coding my own filter?
My Filter code basically is:

```
.filter('selectedFilter', function (underscore) {
  return function (elements, filter) {
    var result = [];
    for (var idx in elements) {
      var element = elements[idx];
      if (underscore.intersection(element.selected, filter.selected).length === filter.selected.length) {
        result.push(element[idx]);
      }
    }
    return result;
  }
}
```

I am using the filter like so:

```
<ion-item ng-repeat="element in vm.filtered = ( vm.filterElements(vm.searchFilter)) 
track by $index"></ion-item>
```

where

```
  function filterElements (filter) {
    var filteredElements = $filter('selectedFilter')(vm.elements, filter);
    return filteredTrees;
  }
```

Comment: You are expecting too much...write own filter

Comment: I did that and I can filter the selected array with that filter. However I can not filter for the `$` property anymore. Is that somehow possible with chaining?

Comment: No idea without seeing the code

Comment: not showing how you are using them both. Why not do it all in your custom filter?

Comment: I added how I use It. That is my question, how to be able to write a custom filter that will still be able to use the `$` property

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103307/discussion-between-niklas-and-charlietfl).

Answer (score 1):

You should right your own filter, because you want to different options here.

```
angular.filter('special', function(){

    return function mySpecificFilter(array, filter){
       return array.filter(function(element){
        element.name === filter.$ && /* filter to check selected field     */
      })
 }

})
```

Comment: thanks for pointing me at Array.prototype.filter() I will check that

Comment: your first function in filter only works for element.name so the `$` functionality is voided

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Array#filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) with plain Javascript:

```js
var array = [{ number: 1, name: 'name1', selected: [100, 400, 210, 103, 102] }, { number: 2, name: 'name2', selected: [100, 400, 210, 104, 102] }, { number: 3, name: 'name3', selected: [100, 103] }],
    search = { selected: [100, 103] },
    result = array.filter(function (a) {
        return Object.keys(search).some(function (k) {
            return search[k].every(function (b) {
                return ~a[k].indexOf(b);
            });
        });
    });

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: Thank you for your pure javascript solution but I am failing to get it to work in angular.